# Alternative way of using pointers to const data?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, const-correctness

In my C99 program, I have a struct with pointers to floats (denoting a matrix). The struct goes through a set of routines, called from, say, `main`.

I'd like to make sure that the content of the structs (the actual values in the matrix) are unchanged by the called routines. The data should however be able to be changed from `main`.

I've come up with the following solution, where I define a pointer to `const` data:

```
struct math_object {
    const real_t *p_to_matrix;
};
```

Doing so, none of the called routines can change the underlying data pointed to by `p_to_matrix`.

At the very beginning of the program I allocate some memory pointed to by `user_matrix`, I initialize the values, and point `p_to_matrix` to `user_matrix` using this (kinda ugly) cast:

```
real_t *user_matrix;
... allocate memory ...
... initialize the data ...
math_object1.p_to_matrix = (const real_t *) user_matrix;
```

Then I only allow the user to change the values pointed to by `user_matrix`.

Is there a better/cleaner/safer way of passing data around that should be considered `const` by called routines, but where you need to change the same data now and again?

Comment: It can't be enforced, but why not simply have the function declared to take a `const real_*` argument? Then both the compiler and the reader of the code will know that the function will not modify the data.

Comment: I have 20+ matrices in a struct, so then the argument lists get very long..

Comment: `p_to_matrix* points to a 1D array, not a matrix (i.e. 2D array). And don't cast unless you have completely understood all implications. Said that, ples provide a [mcve]. It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: You can convert a pointer to an unqualified type to a pointer to a const-qualified version of the same type without a cast. So the cast in your example is redundant.

Comment: @Olaf In the actual code I have double pointers, but I removed them here for clarity. I don't think a M/C/V example is in order, because it's more of a design question.

Comment: @IanAbbott I get the following warning (I compile with -Werror): 

error: assigning to
      'const real_t **' (aka 'const double **') from 'double *[N]' discards qualifiers in
      nested pointer types [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]

I'd like to be able to compile my entire program without warnings.

Comment: @Nibor: Something like `int **` is not even usable as 2D array, cannot represent one nor point to one! A 1D array at least can be use to manually do the 2D indexing. If you have a `**`, that is a significant different! See [ask]! You are expected to provide **all** necessary information!

Comment: @Nibor: Then that warning is due to something you're not telling us. The code you gave us contained no pointers to pointers or arrays of pointers.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Sorry, you're right. I thought the behavior would be the same for double pointers, but it isn't. The original question still holds though! I'm looking for a clean way of passing matrices inside structs to functions, such that those functions can not alter the data inside the matrices.

Comment: With the goal "I'd like to make sure that the content of the structs (the actual values in the matrix) are unchanged by the called routines. ", using `const` as in `math_read_that(const struct math_object* obj)` is sufficient as the contents of `*obj` can not change with compliant code.  But you want _more_ than that.  You also want objects pointed by the fields also do not change.  Using a field of `const real_t *p_to_matrix;` is likely insufficient too as that prevents changes to the object it points to, but not objects pointed to by the sub-fields objects pointers. Go with @dasblinkenlight

Comment: I'd represent the matrix as a 1D array, and store a pointer to the zeroth element. If the dimensions are variable, you'd need to store the dimensions too. If you know the length of each row (i.e. the number of columns), it's easy to convert a 2D pair of indices into a 1D index in order to access the elements of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to not let the users of your API see the structure of `struct math_object` at all, providing functions to interact with it instead. This way you would be able to keep the pointer non-const, and avoid casting altogether:

```
// This goes into the header file for your API
struct math_object; // Forward declaration
struct math_object* math_allocate(/* allocation parameters go here */);
void math_free(struct math_object* obj);
const real_t *math_get_matrix(struct math_object* obj);
```

You could prevent the user from seeing pointers to values, at the expense of making twice as many wrappers:

```
real_t math_get_matrix_val(struct math_object* obj, size_t row, size_t col);
void math_set_matrix_val(struct math_object* obj, size_t row, size_t col, real_t val);
```

Now you can define `struct math_object` inside your implementation with a non-const pointer, because the users of your API see only the header, so they have no access to the internals:

```
struct math_object {
    real_t *p_to_matrix;
};
```

> I have 20+ matrices in a `struct`, so then the argument lists get very long.

You have two approaches to give API users access to the 20+ matrices:

- **Make 20+ API functions, one for each matrix** - this approach works best when the matrices represent unrelated things, or
- **Make one function that takes matrix "number" or some other identifier** - this works when matrices represent similar concepts, almost an array of matrices.

Comment: But then the called routines could still change the data, right? That's what I would like to prevent.

Comment: Using `const` self-document that the called routine did not change the referenced object.  So maybe `math_change_this(struct math_object* obj)` and `math_read_that(const struct math_object* obj)`?

Comment: @chux But a `const struct` is not the same as a `struct` with `const` fields, right? I would still be able to change the data pointed at inside the struct.

Comment: @Nibor There is no way to prevent modification without making a copy each time the access is requested. C provides no certain way to prevent undefined behavior, which is part of the reason the language is so compact. The code operates at the level very close to assembly language, so if you give users a pointer to something that does not generate a trap on writing, the users would be able to write to that location (at the cost of triggering undefined behavior).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Agreed, but at least I'd like my program to be in such a way that the compiler gives warnings when I try to change data in some routines that I'm not supposed to change. My version does exactly that!

Comment: @Nibor Not if the users cast away the const-ness explicitly (see [demo](http://ideone.com/zWUNua)). They would have to do the same thing with the result of `math_get_matrix`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're right, and I was aware of that. But having pointers to `const` data builds some robustness (and some self-documentation) into the code. IMHO, being able to do a lot of nasty things in C should not prevent people to at least try to write clean code.

Comment: @Nibor "a const struct is not the same as a struct with const fields, right?" Yes, they are not the same.  But the idea is comparing _pointers_ to a `const foo` versus `foo`.  "I would still be able to change the data pointed at inside the struct." Not without invoking UB.  So a compliant `math_read_that(const struct math_object* obj)` would not be able to modify the referenced data.

Comment: @chux What is UB?

Comment: @Nibor UB stands for "Undefined behavior".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks. @chux But `math_read_that` can freely do something like `obj->p_to_matrix[0] = 42.0`. That's what I would like to prevent, only the user should be able to set these values (possibly through functions).

Comment: @Nibor Yes `obj->p_to_matrix[0] = 42.0` is allowed with `p_to_matrix` as a non-`const` pointer.  It is not allowed if it was an array.  Thanks for clarifying your dilemma.  Yet I agree with this answer's primary approach - hide the fields.